# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) for Concrete5.7.5.1

Tags: permissions, server, internal-server-error, concrete5-5.7

I have installed the latest version of Concrete5  5.7.5.1 - after the install I go to the domain name but the website is blank and looking at the console it appears to be a 500 error.

I think it has something to do with the permissions on the server and in the past I have had to put {TMP} in the save.session_path but I don't want to do that again in case I conflict with something else on the server.

This is a linux based server using plesk... if that helps anyone

Comment: Are the folders files, packages, config etc having the correct permissions? Is it a fresh install or an upgrade? I have upgraded yesterday from 5.7.4 and everything is fine

Comment: You need to be more specific. Eg what exactly did you observe that you vaguely summarize as "it appears to be a 500 error"? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).